# Loop through JSON array in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

All,

I have the following array called locations returned by a PHP ajax call to Javascript

```
["41.8818907,-87.6415806",
"41.8819918,-87.6416019",
"0.0,0.0",
"41.8816614,-87.6417209"]
```

How do I loop through these values in Javascript and create an array of markers for google maps?

Ex:

```
function generateMarkers(locations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
      map: map,
      title: locations[i][0]
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost. Try this:

```
function generateMarkers(locations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var coords = locations[i].split(",");
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]),
      map: map,
      title: locations[i]
    });
  }
}
```

The key is that you need latitude and longitude separated. And since they're coming back as comma-delimited, you just gotta `split()` 'em up.